# Post insert multiple data using express js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

im trying to insert data in mongodb using express in the format as below which im not able to achieve.
I need to enter multiple product and serial no in the data field. please help!

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5cbabbd7545ac20f7c912e6a",
        "refno1": "REF1",
        "refno2": "REF2",
        "prodregdate": "2019-04-09T00:00:00.000Z",
        "data": [
            {
                "_id": "5cbabbd7545ac20f7c912e6b",
                "product": "5cb86b45cfafaa1860e29b2a",
                "serialno": "s123"
            },
            { // this data im not able to enter how to do it
                "_id": "5cbabbd7545ac20f7c912e6b",
                "product": "5cb86b45cfafaa1860e29b2a",
                "serialno": "s123"
            },
        ],
        "customer": {
            "_id": "5c98bb0a42207b16d8fbd3cf",
            "customername": "Raghav Update"
        },
        "customertype": {
            "_id": "5c7a1a1d4913fa08ac75c027",
            "customertype": "Government "
        },
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

// My Schema

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    const ProductRegistrationSchema = new Schema({
        //Product Details
        _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId },
        refno1: { type: String },
        refno2: { type: String },
        data: [{
            product: {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "product"                      
            },
             //DATES
            //OEM
            oemwarrantyfrom: { type: Date },
           oemwarrantyto: { type: Date },
           //SERVICE PROVIDER
           warrantyfrom: { type: Date },
           warrantyto: { type: Date },
           serialno: { type: String },    
        }],

        prodregdate: { type: Date },
        //Details of Customer buying the product
        customer: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "customer" 
        },
        customertype: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "customertype" 
        },
        department: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "customersubdepartment" 
        },
         remarks: { type: String },
        entrydate: {
            type: Date,
            dafault: Date.now
        } 

module.exports = ProductRegistration = mongoose.model('productregistration', ProductRegistrationSchema);
```

// My Routes just for add

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Product = require("../../../models/Master/Products");
//importing the model of ProductRegistrationSchema
const ProdReg = require('../../../models/Entries/ProductRegistration');

//Creating a new ProductRegistration Data
router.post('/add', (req, res)=>{
    const newProdReg = new ProdReg({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        refno1: req.body.refno1,
        refno2: req.body.refno2,
        prodregdate: req.body.prodregdate,
        data: {
          product: req.body.productid,
          oemwarrantyfrom: req.body.oemwarrantyfrom,
          oemwarrantyto: req.body.oemwarrantyto,
          warrantyfrom: req.body.warrantyfrom,
          warrantyto: req.body.warrantyto,
          serialno: req.body.serialno,
        },
        customer: req.body.customerid,
        customertype: req.body.customertypeid,
        department: req.body.customersubdepartmentid,
        remarks: req.body.remarks
        // deliverydate: req.body.deliverydate,
        // address: req.body.address,
        // assignedto: req.body.employeesid,
        // warrantyprovider: req.body.serviceproviderid,
        // oemwarrantyprovider: req.body.oemcompanyid,
        // warrantystartdate: req.body.warrantystartdate,
        // warrantyexpiredate: req.body.warrantyexpiredate,


    });
     newProdReg.save().then(prodreg => res.json(prodreg));

});
```

im not able to enter 2 product and serial no in the data field. One one is getting entered.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make your request JSON in the proper format if you want to insert two products which you are getting from request data.

For example, your request JSON should be in the flowing format:

```
{"refno1":"x", "refno2": "y", "prodregdate": "2019-04-19T18:30:00.000Z","data": [{"product": "product_1_object_id","oemwarrantyfrom":"2019-04-19T18:30:00.000Z", "oemwarrantyto": "2019-04-19T18:30:00.000Z","warrantyfrom":"2019-04-19T18:30:00.000Z", "warrantyto":"2019-04-19T18:30:00.000Z","serialno":"123" },{"product": "product_2_object_id","oemwarrantyfrom":"", "oemwarrantyto": "2019-04-19T18:30:00.000Z","warrantyfrom":"2019-04-19T18:30:00.000Z", "warrantyto":"2019-04-19T18:30:00.000Z","serialno":"456" }],"customersubdepartmentid":"departement_object_id","customerid":"customer_object_id","customertypeid":"customer_type_object_id","remarks":"anything"}
```

If you are using POSTMAN then you can try this JSON in the "raw" option.

Then in your code, it should be like below:

```
router.post('/add', (req, res)=>{
    const newProdReg = new ProdReg({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        refno1: req.body.refno1,
        refno2: req.body.refno2,
        prodregdate: req.body.prodregdate,
        data: req.body.data,                      // This will be type array with two products details
        customer: req.body.customerid,
        customertype: req.body.customertypeid,
        department: req.body.customersubdepartmentid,
        remarks: req.body.remarks
    });
     newProdReg.save().then(prodreg => res.json(prodreg));

});
```

Please match your request param with JSON I took it from your schema.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but when i enter the data its is not coming. Same code but did not change any thing

Comment: `code`{
    "_id": "5cbaf8fdc7d11814e447bd12",
    "refno1": "x",
    "refno2": "y",
    "prodregdate": "2019-04-19T00:00:00.000Z",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5cbaf8fdc7d11814e447bd13"
        }
    ],
    "customer": "5c98bb0a42207b16d8fbd3cf",
    "customertype": "5c7a1a1d4913fa08ac75c027",
    "department": "5c88a0062a612422c087e201",
    "remarks": "anything",
    "__v": 0
}`code`